# How to calculate columns that have circular dependency in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this-

```
                   Tstamp    Token     LTP  Cum_bsdiffs  Cum_ltpdiffs  counts Entry    Correl  Exit  ltpchange  ltpcumchange  ltppercumchange
0     2018-10-29 11:40:33   415745  138.40          NaN           NaN       0     0       NaN     0          0             0                0
1     2018-10-29 11:40:34   415745  138.40       -200.0          0.00       1     0       NaN     0          0             0                0
2     2018-10-29 11:40:34   415745  138.35      -1437.0         -0.05       2     0       NaN     0          0             0                0
3     2018-10-29 11:40:36   415745  138.35      -1337.0         -0.05       3     0       NaN     0          0             0                0
```

Now the columns `Entry`,`Exit`,`ltpchange` and `ltpcumchange` are interdependent as follows-

> 1. `Entry` becomes "Buy" or "Sell" based on a condition depending on
>      other columns. Otherwise it will remain 0.
>
>    2. Just when `Entry` becomes not equal to 0, `ltpchange` starts taking changes in subsequent values of `LTP`. Otherwise it will
>         remain 0.
>    3. `ltpcumchange` will take cumulative sum of `ltpchange`.
>    4. Just when `ltpcumchange` reaches a target value (any direction), `Exit` will become 1.
>    5. `Entry` will remain "Buy" or "Sell", depending on its previous row, untill `Exit`becomes 1 after which it will revert to 0.

I have used `iterrows`() to go for this logic, however, it is superslow. My dataframe contains more than 2 million rows and it is going by the speed of almost 5 rows per second.

I tried using dataframe column logic but failed to get the desired result. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Seems that your dataframe changes based only on those 4 columns so you can exclude the rest. Also, given the above example, what would the desire output look like? Should you need help in editing your question do take a look at how to create [mcve]

Comment: I gess you want to create a robot for trading and you don't want to share your strategie. But if you do not share your code, we cannot optimize it. iterrows() is slow, there might be a way to avoid using it.

Comment: @CharlesR yes you are right. but i have mentioned all the logic that i want to be 'vectorized'

Comment: Maybe try to use a maximum of .loc[] in order to filter the rows you want to modify on each step of your code. Also numpy is good for vectorizing your code, ty to use np.where, np.select, np.choice

Comment: ``iterrows()`` will be slow indeed. Recommend using numpy as well and modify the elements of the array as the length of the array goes on.